# Clicking on page refreshes ; reappears two input elements?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm usig [plugin for drop-down (sub-menu)](http://www.givainc.com/labs/mcdropdown_jquery_plugin.cfm) in my HTML. My HTML looks like following:-

**HTML**

```
<div class="taxonomy" id="taxonomy_id" style="height: 54px">
<input type="text" class="category" name="category" id="category" value="" />
<input type="text" class="category" name="category_1" id="category_1" value="" /></div>  
</body>
```

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function (){
  $("#category").mcDropdown("#categorymenu",{targetColumnSize: 1});

  $("#category_1").mcDropdown("#categorymenu_1",{targetColumnSize: 1});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/3JVJy/)

Now, when I hit refresh once the page is loaded, I see the rest of html elements remain static on page, the dropdown items appears / refreshes instead. With each refresh they are loaded again the focus is changed it seems, can I change this behaviour.

**UPDATE PLUGIN CSS**

```
/* 
    styles for the psuedo-select box 
*/
div.mcdropdown {
    position: absolute;
    border: 1px solid #8e9daa;
    padding: 1px;
    display: -moz-inline-block;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 408px;
    height: 14px;
    padding: 2px;
}

/* style either the input or div where the plug-in is attached to */
div.mcdropdown input, 
div.mcdropdown div {
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #fff;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 98%;
    border: 0;
    padding: 2px 0 0 3px;
    font: 11px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

div.mcdropdown a {
    position: absolute;
    right: 1px;
    top: 1px;
    background: transparent url(../images/mcdropdown/mcdd_select_button_sprite.gif) no-repeat top left;
    display: -moz-inline-block;
    display: inline-block;
    height: 16px;
    width: 15px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 0pt;
    z-index: 2;
    outline: 0;
}

div.mcdropdown a:hover, div.mcdropdown a:focus {
    background-position: 0% -16px;
}

div.mcdropdown a:active {
    background-position: 0% -32px;
    outline: none; /* hide dotted outline in Firefox */
}

div.mcdropdownDisabled {
    background-color: #e1e0e0;
    filter:alpha(opacity=75);
    -moz-opacity: 0.75;
    opacity: 0.75;
    -khtml-user-select: none;
    -o-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-focus: ignore; 
    -moz-user-input: disabled; 
}

div.mcdropdownDisabled input {
    cursor: default;
}

div.mcdropdownDisabled a:hover, div.mcdropdownDisabled a:focus {
    background-position: 0 0;
    cursor: default;
}

/* 
    styles for the dropdown menu 
*/
ul.mcdropdown_menu {
    display: none;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    list-style-type: none;
    /* float so we can calculate the size of the columns */
    float: left;
    clear: both;
    z-index: 10000;
    -khtml-user-select: none;
    -o-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-focus: ignore; 
    -moz-user-input: disabled; 
}

ul.mcdropdown_menu ul {
    display: none;
    font: 11px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    /* float so we can calculate the size of the columns */
/*
    float: left;
*/
}

/* -- Sub-Menus -- */
ul.mcdropdown_menu ul {
    position: absolute;
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0px;
    margin-left: 30px;
    padding: 0px;
    z-index: 10000;
}
ul.mcdropdown_menu ul li {
    margin: 0px;
    min-width: 150px;
    _width: 150px; /* ie6 min-width hack */
}


/* color schema */
ul.mcdropdown_menu {
/*
    height: 19px;
*/
    height: auto;
    background-color: #e1e0e0;
    padding: 5px 5px;
    /* define font here for IE6 */
    font: 11px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

ul.mcdropdown_menu li {
    padding: 2px 20px 2px 6px;
    /* this is needed to ensure that all browsers have the same line-height--fixes issues in Chrome (Mac) and IE10 */
    line-height: 14px;
}

/* we don't use "ul.mcdropdown_menu > li" here so that IE6 knows how to style the root level */
ul.mcdropdown_menu li.mc_root {
    cursor: pointer;
    white-space: nowrap;
    color: #666;
    border-top: 1px solid #fff;
    padding: 2px 20px 2px 6px;
    margin: 0 10px;
}

ul.mcdropdown_menu > li.mc_endcol {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
}

/* this is for IE6 only */
ul.mcdropdown_menu li.mc_hover {
    background-color: #ccc !important;
}

ul.mcdropdown_menu > li:hover {
    border-top: 1px solid #999;
    background-color: #999 !important;
    color: #fff;
}

ul.mcdropdown_menu > li:hover.mc_endcol {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #999;
}

ul.mcdropdown_menu > li:hover + li:not(.mc_firstrow) {
    border-top: 1px solid #999;
}

ul.mcdropdown_menu li.mc_parent {
    padding-right: 20px !important;
    background: url(../images/mcdropdown/mcdd_icon_normal.gif) no-repeat 100% 50%;
}

ul.mcdropdown_menu li:hover.mc_parent {
    background: #999 url(../images/mcdropdown/mcdd_icon_hover.gif) no-repeat 100% 50% !important;
    color: #fff !important;
}

ul.mcdropdown_menu ul {
    background: #f0f0f0;
    /* add a slight border for better visualization of deep menus */
    border: 1px solid #d0d0d0;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    /* IE 6/7 will bleed through the background color if we don't set the visibility to hidden */
    visibility: hidden;
}

ul.mcdropdown_menu ul li {
    background: #f0f0f0;
    padding-left: 16px !important;
    border-top: 1px solid #fff;
    color: #666;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

ul.mcdropdown_menu ul li.mc_firstrow {
    border-top: 1px solid #f0f0f0;
}

ul.mcdropdown_menu ul li.mc_endcol {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
}

ul.mcdropdown_menu ul li:hover {
    background-color: #d6d6d6;
    border-top: 1px solid #dedede;
    color: #666;
}

ul.mcdropdown_menu ul li.mc_endcol:hover {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #dedede;
}

ul.mcdropdown_menu ul li:hover + li:not(.mc_firstrow) {
    border-top: 1px solid #dedede;
}

/*
 * drop down shadows
 */
div.mcdropdown_shadow {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    margin: 3px 0 0 3px;
    /* for IE6, we use just a square transparent image */
    background: #000;
    filter :alpha(opacity=33);
}

/* ie6 ignores this selector */
html>body div.mcdropdown_shadow {
    /* let's use a transparent PNG */
    margin: 5px 0 0 5px;
    padding: 5px 0 0 5px;
    background: transparent url(../images/mcdropdown/shadow.png) right bottom no-repeat !important;
    /* remove the filter for IE7 */
    filter: none;
}

/* 
 * styles for the dropdown menu 
 */
/* autocomplete styles */
ul.mcdropdown_autocomplete {
    display: block;
  position: absolute;
    height: auto;
    max-height: 210px;
  overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: auto;
  clear: both;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    background-color: #e1e0e0;
    z-index: 10000;

    margin: 0px;
    list-style-type: none;
    width: 392px;
    font: 11px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

ul.mcdropdown_autocomplete ul {
    display: none;
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}
ul.mcdropdown_autocomplete ul li {
    margin: 0px;
}

ul.mcdropdown_autocomplete li {
  display: block;
    font: 11px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    cursor: pointer;
    white-space: nowrap;
    color: #666;
    border-top: 1px solid #fff;
    padding: 2px 26px 2px 6px;
}

ul.mcdropdown_autocomplete li.mc_endcol {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
}

ul.mcdropdown_autocomplete li.mc_parent {
    padding-right: 20px !important;
    background: url(../images/mcdropdown/mcdd_icon_normal.gif) no-repeat 100% 50%;
}

ul.mcdropdown_autocomplete li.mc_hover {
    border-top: 1px solid #999;
    background-color: #999 !important;
    color: #fff;
}

ul.mcdropdown_autocomplete li.mc_hover_parent {
    background: #999 url(../images/mcdropdown/mcdd_icon_hover.gif) no-repeat 100% 50% !important;
    color: #fff !important;
}
```

Comment: Include your overriding CSS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `!important` to your css that must be used.

```
.myOverride:focus {
   display: block !important;
}
```

Just like that. This was an example, but you'd have to change it up a little to suit your needs.

Comment: in ur example what is .myOverride?

Comment: .myOverride would link to let's say, a div in html such as:
`<div class="myOverride">stuff</div>`

Comment: @got it so i can add this in <style type="text/css"> or in the plugin css code?

Comment: It would be added into either a `.css` file or `<style type="text/css">`

Comment: I'm using div class taxonomy as both input which is effected by page refresh are included in this div

Comment: Not too sure then, sorry. :(